# How to create a jsp web form to post data to the web service and display result from the web service

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am using Eclipse and Tomcat server for developing a web application with Web Services.

When I test the web service, I get :

"Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here..."

The IDE does provide a facility to create a test web client for testing the web service.

However, I want to write my own JSP page from scratch to consume this web service...

Please provide me some sample code / related links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in following pattern :

1.Create a form in jsp to take input data.
2.Retrieve those data from servlet.
3.Make a call to webservice using client generated from WSDL and send response back to jsp.

Addition of a new layer that will interact with service would be an better design

Comment: life.java: I wish to achieve something like: (i) I create my web service (ii) Then write a JSP form / Servlet to interact with the Web Service and do some processing (iii) give output to the user... Is it possible without generating the client from WSDL ? Thanks

Comment: @Mahendra Liya , Why you don't want to generate client ?

Comment: life.java: Because it generate two many JSP files... (to be precise 4 in number). Moreover, the code generated in the JSP files is very rough... So I want to have my own code from scratch..

Comment: @Mahendra Liya , then I don't see any issues for you to go for webservice client.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help.

1.Download the wsdl file related to webservice.

2.Generate clients using wsdl2java command [ You can find this in Axis2 or Apache CXF )

1. Include all generated client code,in your class path
2. Post the data from your jsp to the servlet which includes generated client code to make webservice request